# CMSIS without HAL

Tags: stm32, cmsis, hal

Is it possible to create a project in System Workbench for STM32 with CMSIS but without HAL library? My target microcontroller is STM32L053R8 on a Nucleo board. When I create a with HAL and delete all the files related to this library, I get a lot of errors and some source files can't see header files. Generally, I want to have clean project with CMSIS only.

Comment: Then just select no firmware instead of HAL when you configure the project.

Comment: I tried that and It doesn't work. When I select the project without firmware, there is no CMSIS inside. Unless I have to add it manually.

Comment: Best tutorial with accurate setting I have found to create project in STM32CUBE IDE with CMSIS but without HAL library and it work perfectly. Link:
http://www.pomad.fr/node/67

Answer (score 5):

I've found it.

In the properties of the project, you need to go to **C/C++ build** -> **Settings** -> **Tool Settings** -> **Includes**. In the **Include paths (-l)**, remove the HAL-related directories and add a catalogue with your own prepared drivers. Save the settings.

[image: fsdfdsfds]

The last step is to rebuild indexes.

[image]